# Axis and data change on zoom out/zoom in

Tags: dc.js

I am designing dc.js application which displays top n results and I want the graph to display more results like top(n+10) results when user zooms out.Is there a way to do so?

Comment: That's what some people mean by "semantic zoom." There's a PR here to add the event handling: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/699 . On top of that you could use a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted) to filter what's shown in the chart. Also related: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/416

Comment: Sorry, I know this is not an answer, just gardening the links here.